# Error when run file createdb.sh when install Hyperledger Explorer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

When I ran the createdb.sh file, there was an error:\

```
could not change directory to "/root/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/fabric-samples/blockchain-explorer/app/persistence/fabric/postgreSQL/db": Permission denied
psql: error: ./explorerpg.sql: No such file or directory
could not change directory to "/root/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/fabric-samples/blockchain-explorer/app/persistence/fabric/postgreSQL/db": Permission denied
psql: error: ./updatepg.sql: No such file or directory</code>
```

I follow the instructions in [https://github.com/hyperledger/blockchain-explorer\](https://github.com/hyperledger/blockchain-explorer%5C)
I have done all the steps and apply permission to db/

There is file create.sh

[image: create.sh]

and folder db

[image: db]

Comment: Can you tell me exactly the command used in the form of code?

Comment: @myeongkilkim
command sudo -u postgres ./createdb.sh
after run command chmod -R 775 db/

Comment: @myeongkilkim ths u very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# this is your command
sudo -u postgres ~~
```

With the sudo -u option you run the command as the postgres user.

---

https://helpmanual.io/help/sudo/

```
sudo
  -u, --user=user             run command (or edit file) as specified user name
                              or ID
```

---

It is expected that the postgres user will not have privileged access to the /root directory.
Here are three solutions.

#### 1. Change the file mode bits /root dir

- Not recommended.

```
sudo chmod -R 775 /root
```

#### 2. Add postgres to super user group

- [ubuntu18.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-sudo-user-on-ubuntu-quickstart)
- [centos7](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-sudo-user-on-centos-quickstart)

```
# ubuntu 18.04
sudo usermod -aG sudo postgres
su - postgres

# centos7
sudo usermod -aG wheel postgres
su - postgres
```

#### 3. Independently divide the workspace

- Running applications under the root directory is dangerous and contradicts the Linux user philosophy.

1. Create a new workspace under the /home directory
2. Set permissions for the new workspace
3. Move your application and code
4. Grant permissions to postgres